# What is the reasoning behind having to declare temporary variables rather than having bindings?

Tags: pharo

Out of all the features Pharo has, the `|a b c|` style of declaring temporary variables definitely feels like something that should have stayed in the 80s. Is there any benefit from declaring uninitialized variables and then doing assignment on them rather than having let bindings?

It is true that the IDE will be helpful in making such declarations, but I found it to be annoying when removing assignments as the empty declarations would still remain in.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Would it be possible to make declaration of temp vars optional in Smalltalk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31191014/would-it-be-possible-to-make-declaration-of-temp-vars-optional-in-smalltalk)

Answer (score 4):

I don't know the original reason but using Smalltalk every week, I see multiple advantages.

- It makes the code more readable. When we see a variable we can know if it's a temporary variable or an instance variable by looking at the declared temporary variables.
- It defines the scope of the variable (Since it can be only in the scope of a block for example)
- It allows better code completion

I guess it also simplifies the implementation of the Compiler.

Comment: Also: nothing prevents anyone from implementing that but it seems like a lot of work and we're a small community. I guess that, once you get used to it, you don't think about changing the compiler for such a thing.

Comment: Also: what if there is a typo and the intent wasn't to add a new temporary but to use another one? The explicit declaration allows the IDE to better assist the programmer.